Does DNF (Do not fit) mean that I should remove the component?
I have two schematics. On the ethernet-page, I can see this cross.


Question:
Does that mean I should not use the resistor there, like leaving ETH_CLK unconnected, or should I connect the ETH_CLK to the 0R resistor, directly?
The schematics can be downloaded here.

To me both mean that R69 is optional. Meaning that in the actual PCB, there will be pads for it in case it is needed.

@Big6 To me, it feels like that I should not use a resistor there and leave it unconnected.

You can leave it unconnected but the purpose of showing R69 in the schematc is to make sure it shows up in the actual PCB layout. Your choice to leave it open or not.

You haven't provided any background as to what the schematic is for, but I would guess a development kit or evaluation module (EVM).
Missed the link at the end of your question. Yes this is an evaluation kit (EVM).
EVMs are designed to allow testing the device in different configurations so provide routing and footprints for components that allow evaluating it in these different ways. Depending which components are fitted it will operate in a certain way.
In this case it looks like they provide options for an external clock source driven from the STM or a crystal oscillator. To use ETH_CLK you would fit R69 and presumably DNI R68 and R64. To use the oscillator just off the schematic (NX3225GA) you would use the configuration shown (R64/R68 populated and R69 DNI).
In a real device you would have picked the option you would want to use, and the unused parts (and isolation resistors) would be dropped from the design entirely.

+1 Very good answer. Just a side comment. Sometimes DNF also may be an acknowledgement that other variants of this design are possible, which would make sense given that this an EVB.
